# x is not defined, setTimeout problem

Tags: javascript, settimeout

With the following code I get a `clock is not defined` error, why?

```
$(function(){   
    function clock() {
        var nd = new Date();
        var h, m, s;
        h = nd.getHours();
        m = nd.getMinutes();
        s = nd.getSeconds();
        if (h <= 9) h = "0" + h;
        if (m <= 9) m = "0" + m;
        if (s <= 9) s = "0" + s;
        $('#digital-clock .hour').text(h+':');
        $('#digital-clock .min').text(m+':');
        $('#digital-clock .sec').text(s);
    }
    setTimeout('clock()', 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because when you pass a string to `setTimeout`, the code inside it will be executed in global scope at timeout time. Code in global scope doesn't have access to any of the local variables present at the time you call `setTimeout`.

Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`, it invariably sucks (it's basically a deferred `eval`, and we all hate `eval` eh?). Instead use a `Function` object:

```
setTimeout(clock, 1000);
```

you can use an inline function expression to create your function too, for example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var nd= new Date();
    ...
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Things that invariably suck are always to be avoided.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$(function(){   
    function clock() {
        var nd = new Date();
        var h, m, s;
        h = nd.getHours();
        m = nd.getMinutes();
        s = nd.getSeconds();
        if (h <= 9) h = "0" + h;
        if (m <= 9) m = "0" + m;
        if (s <= 9) s = "0" + s;
        $('#digital-clock .hour').text(h+':');
        $('#digital-clock .min').text(m+':');
        $('#digital-clock .sec').text(s);
    }
    setTimeout(clock, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this?

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        var nd = new Date();
        var h, m, s;
        h = nd.getHours();
        m = nd.getMinutes();
        s = nd.getSeconds();
        if (h <= 9) h = "0" + h;
        if (m <= 9) m = "0" + m;
        if (s <= 9) s = "0" + s;
        $('#digital-clock .hour').text(h+':');
        $('#digital-clock .min').text(m+':');
        $('#digital-clock .sec').text(s);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Unless there's some reason you need to reference the function by name later... ?